# C connection refused

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Hello i just write a quite big email server - client, it all works, exept the connection to the server

the problem is the port. i set the port on both (server - client) to 49255, but the connection is refused. when i try to print out the port, normally or with ntohl() the port is set to 0

client

```
void init_struct(struct sockaddr_in *adress, long unsigned int ip) {
    memset(adress, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    adress->sin_port = htonl(49255);
    adress->sin_family = AF_INET;
    adress->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    print("Set port to %d\n", n adress->sin_port);
}
```

server

```
void init_struct(struct sockaddr_in* server) {
    memset(server, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server->sin_port = htonl(49255);
    printf("Set port to %d\n", server->sin_port);
}
```

and to add something: the server - client is running on the same machine

the output is:

```
Set port to 0
Cant connect to server, please try again
: Connection refused
```

on the client side.

on the server side it also print "set port to 0"

Comment: You have to use `htons()`, not `htonl()`.

Comment: yes thanks now it works. but can you explain me why it makes a difference when i use htonl

Comment: Because shorts and longs are different sizes, and converting between host and network order is different. The port number is a short.

Answer (score 3):

The `sin_port` field is 16 bits, but the `htonl` function converts 32 bit values.  So when you pass the value 49255, which in hex is 0x0000C067, you get back the value 0x67C00000.  When this value is converted back to 16 bit, only the lower 16 bits are retained and you're left with 0.

You instead want to use `htons` which is for 16 bit values.

```
server->sin_port = htons(49255);
```